# Oracle Reports - String field empty using dblink

Tags: oracle, plsql, dblink, oraclereports

I have a dblink called **times**.

Im creating oracle report.

This is my query:

```
select 
   tbloola_master."account_name" acctname 
from
   "tblOOHA_Master"@times tbloola_master;
```

**Problem:**
When I run the report, **I GOT EMPTY REPORT**.

I tried converting the field using TO_CHAR and it works.

```
select 
   TO_CHAR(tbloola_master."account_name") acctname 
from
   "tblOOHA_Master"@times tbloola_master;
```

I don't understand.Please help.Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why TO_CHAR makes report show something, but I know that creating objects (tables, column names) using double quotes is a bad idea. If possible, get rid of those.

Comment: So how should I modify my query without using double quotes?

Comment: You can't, if you really created column name using double quotes, such as `create table "tblOOHA_Master" ("account_name" varchar2(20), ...)`. You'd have to rename everything; by default, Oracle creates it in uppercase, but you can reference it any way you want (upper/lower/mixed case). But, if you used double quotes, you have to pay attention to letter case every time you reference that object/column, enclose it into double quotes and never fail.

Comment: @ktaro probably your field, namely `f_acctname` is of type number, and should be cınverted to `char` from property palette...

Comment: You can't modify field's datatype in Reports directly, @Barbaros (at least, that's what I think). Datatype is *inherited* from column's datatype. If there's a function applied to it, the it is datatype returned by that function. However, you can't just *click* in the Property Palette and change NUMBER to CHAR.

Comment: @Littlefoot you're right, recalled that changing the type was not easy as clicking :) thank you.